# How to split text into an array with different formats in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have this string that I would like to split into an array

```
string = "2009C20402052C3200C3360C22503201C"
```

This is how I would like it to split.

```
result = ["2009C", "2040", "2052C", "3200C", "3360B", "2250", "3201C"]
```

Basically I would like to know how to split it, if there are 4 digits on their own or 4 digits followed by a C (5 characters in total). How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split into groups of four digits followed by a C (five characters in total), or just four digits if the C isn't there, you can do it like this:

```
const rex = /\d{4}C?/g;
let match;
const parts = [];
while ((match = rex.exec(string)) !== null) {
    parts.push(match[1]);
}
```

The regular expression is `\d{4}` (four digits) and `C?` (optional C).

Live Example

```js
const string = "2009C20402052C3200C3360C22503201C";

const rex = /\d{4}C?/g;
let match;
const parts = [];
while ((match = rex.exec(string)) !== null) {
    parts.push(match[0]);
}
console.log(parts);
```

Or if you like you can do it while hiding the loop in the `replace` and `split` functions (the loop is still there — two of them, actually —just not in *your* code):

```
const parts = string.replace(/\d{4}C?/g, "$&\n")
                    .trim().split("\n")
```

Live Example:

```js
const string = "2009C20402052C3200C3360C22503201C";

const parts = string.replace(/\d{4}C?/g, "$&\n")
                    .trim().split("\n")
console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick which seems to be working is to replace every four digit number with that same number preceded by space.  Then, trim that string, and split on single space.

```js
var string = "2009C20402052C3200C3360C22503201C"
var parts = string.replace(/(\d{4})/g, " $1").trim().split(" ");
console.log(parts);
```